# JSON return error as undefined when the value is numeric

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ckeditor

not sure where the errors lies in what I am trying to achieve.

I am working with someone else's code and unfortunately they have used numbers for div ids in some places.

These number ids are used in various places and if I can, I want to find a way to keep things as they are.

So,

returning the following in JSON:

```
editorID: "1000"
```

And in my AJAX call i use that return like so:

```
var editorID = response.editorID;

CKEDITOR.instances.editorID.insertHtml('<br><img class="buildimage" src="http://www.buildsanctuary.com/phpLibs/bulletproof-master/src/userBuildImages/'+response.imageName+'"><br>');
```

However this gives me an error saying that the editorID is undefined.

As you can I already use a JSON response in my code, this works fine so its not a problem with datatypes etc.

I also tried to do:

```
alert(response.editorID);
```

which gave me the correct value.

When I tried putting a number directly into CKEditor insertHTML code it was showing my syntax errors so maybe thats the issue. If so, any work around for it?

Thanks. Craig.

Comment: How about `CKEDITOR.instances[editorID]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable as a property, you have to use `[]` notation:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[editorID].insertHtml('<br><img class="buildimage" src="http://www.buildsanctuary.com/phpLibs/bulletproof-master/src/userBuildImages/'+response.imageName+'"><br>');
```

When you use `.editorID`, it's looking for a property named `editorID`, not `1000`.

You also have to use this syntax when the property isn't a valid identifer. So if you wanted to put the number directly, you would write:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['1000'].insertHtml('<br><img class="buildimage" src="http://www.buildsanctuary.com/phpLibs/bulletproof-master/src/userBuildImages/'+response.imageName+'"><br>');
```

Comment: Perfect, now I understand :)